# Cannot install Ubuntu 22.04 live server (ARM64) with VMWare Fusion 13 or Tech Preview

Tags: server, arm

I downloaded the ISO image of Ubuntu 22.04 live server for ARM64 and tried to install it with VMWare Fusion 13 on Apple M1 macMini.  The screen just hung there after I selected 'Try or Install Ubuntu' from the boot screen. The Tech Preview version behaves the same.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a 2020 MacBook Pro M1.  I got it working with the [daily ISO image](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/jammy/daily-live/current/jammy-desktop-arm64.iso).

Comment: For reference, the Ubuntu Server daily ISOs are at https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/jammy/daily-live/current/