# Black screen after 'Try or install Ubuntu' in VMware Fusion 13 on Apple M1 Pro

Tags: vmware, mac

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 in VMware Fusion 13 on an Apple M1 Pro chip, but it just shows a black screen after selecting 'Try or install Ubuntu'.

I'm downloading the ARM64 versions from [the daily ISOs](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/jammy/daily-live/current/), as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1444500/cannot-install-ubuntu-22-04-live-server-arm64-with-vmware-fusion-13-or-tech-pr). VMware Fusion 13 is now compatible with silicon Macs so what could be the issue?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 is released why are you downloading a daily?

Comment: Because there are no official Desktop releases for ARM chips, only Server.

Comment: Then you are running an unsupported install and that is off topic on this site.

Comment: Well I was hoping to get some advice on how to run an Ubuntu VM on a silicon Mac...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Virtual Machine on a Apple Silicon (M1) macOS Host?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367423/ubuntu-virtual-machine-on-a-apple-silicon-m1-macos-host)

Answer (score 1):

https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Documents/The-Unofficial-Fusion-13-for-Apple-Silicon-Companion-Guide/ta-p/2939907 the Companion Guide contains tips and techniques that were provided through the experiences of the broader Fusion community while running the Tech Preview releases on Apple Silicon Macs. It can save you searching the forum for frequently encountered issues.
Here you can find:

> It has been reported by @gsmgmt that the 22.04 daily builds of Ubuntu Desktop fail to boot. This
> is most likely due to the issue described in the topic "Blank console display in Ubuntu 22.10 with
> kernel 5.19.0-31".
> Use the Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 LTS ISO to install an Ubuntu 22.04 virtual machine. If you need
> Ubuntu Desktop functionality, “convert” the Ubuntu Server using the procedure in the topic "How
> to convert Ubuntu Server to Ubuntu Desktop".

Comment: This is the answer. I just did so to get Ubuntu 22 running on my M1 Mac mini. More info here:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1405125/775985